# a[href*=""] not working for a page full of links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with 'n' number of links. I want to collect all links whose href contains xyz.com and then 'randomly' click on one of them.

I have written the following script for it:

```
function clickLinkWithText () {
    var links = $('a[href*="xyz.com"]')
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*links.length);   
    var targetLink = links.get(randomNumber);
    if (targetLink.length) {
        triggerMouseEvent (targetLink[0], "click");
    }
}
/* code for triggerMouseEvent() */
```

However nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using `randomNumber` for referring to `randomNum`! Also  `links.get(number)` returns one element (if any) and not an array (vs. `links.get()`) so using `targetLink.length` doesn't make sense!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions undefined and ibrahim. Can you tell me what should I change in the script to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the right variable, and get rid of the `if` statement as the return value of `get` is the element itself so no further subscripting is needed:

```
function clickLinkWithText () {
    var links = $('a[href*="xyz.com"]');
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*links.length);   
    var targetLink = links.get(randomNum);                      // use the right variable here
    triggerMouseEvent (targetLink, "click");                    // call triggerMouseEvent on the element
}
```

**Note:** The element passed to `triggerMouseEvent` is a DOM element not a jQuery-wrapped one. If `triggerMouseEvent` expects a jQuery object instead, then call `triggerMouseEvent` like so:

```
triggerMouseEvent ($(targetLink), "click");
```

Comment: This works! How do I ensure that I execute this only once. For eg, once the link is clicked, the script should not execute again in the newly loaded page.

Comment: @CuriousDev If the links have IDs, you could store the ID in `localStorage` and then when you are about to click one in the next page, just check if the link's ID is stored or not before deciding to click it. Anyways, this should be a separate question. Look into `localStorage` and if you fail to achieve your desired result, then post another question. Good luck!